# create mysql user with command line

Tags: mysql, command-line

I created a user with this command in mysql command line

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db_name.*` to 'db_name_admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I connect to the db with

```
mysql -u db_name_admin -p -h localhost
```

check to see if I am connectd

```
show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| db_name            |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

then I change to use the right database with

```
use db_name
```

but when I do

```
show tables
```

I get

```
empty set (0.00 sec)
```

when I login with the root account I can see all the tables and records in db_name.
so I guess something is wrong with my GRANT query but I can not figure out what.

when I check the TABLE_PRIVILEGES I see

```
+-----------------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+
| GRANTEE                     | TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME   | PRIVILEGE_TYPE | IS_GRANTABLE |
+-----------------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+
| 'db_name_admin'@'localhost' | def           | db_name      | db_name.*    | SELECT         | YES          |
| 'db_name_admin'@'localhost' | def           | db_name      | db_name.*    | INSERT         | YES          |
| 'db_name_admin'@'localhost' | def           | db_name      | db_name.*    | UPDATE         | YES          |
| 'db_name_admin'@'localhost' | def           | db_name      | db_name.*    | DELETE         | YES          |
| 'db_name_admin'@'localhost' | def           | db_name      | db_name.*    | CREATE         | YES          |
| 'db_name_admin'@'localhost' | def           | db_name      | db_name.*    | DROP           | YES          |
| 'db_name_admin'@'localhost' | def           | db_name      | db_name.*    | REFERENCES     | YES          |
| 'db_name_admin'@'localhost' | def           | db_name      | db_name.*    | INDEX          | YES          |
| 'db_name_admin'@'localhost' | def           | db_name      | db_name.*    | ALTER          | YES          |
| 'db_name_admin'@'localhost' | def           | db_name      | db_name.*    | CREATE VIEW    | YES          |
| 'db_name_admin'@'localhost' | def           | db_name      | db_name.*    | SHOW VIEW      | YES          |
| 'db_name_admin'@'localhost' | def           | db_name      | db_name.*    | TRIGGER        | YES          |
+-----------------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+
```

my database name uses a - sign the command should be

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db-name`.* to 'db_name_admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: thank you for editing my post.
how do you edit to have a code block show up as code ?
I can only manage 1 line at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name.* ...` without the backticks

The backticks "freeze" what you type in there so you get permissions only for a table with the name "db_name.*"